# How to deploy both frontend and backend with the serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am trying to deploy frontend and backends together via serverless framework.
I'm using a mono repository via lerna where the frontend and backend packages are separated into different directories.
So I use multiple serverless.yml s.
How can I deploy both via the same cloud formation name?

It has the following directories:

```
package.json
.. [packages]
.... [backend]
...... package.json
.... [frontend]
...... package.json
```

Where should I put serverless.yml? And how to write serverless.yml?

Answer (score 0):

They will be under the same cloudformation stack because they will have the same service-name in the serverless yml.

It really depends on the type of application. for example if it is a static frontend, the frontend can be packaged into a bundle and then deployed to a public s3 bucket.

If the backend is mainly lambda (Just assuming because this is a common backend approach for the serverless framework). You can just define each lambda handler and then deploy them to AWS. This will create the lambda resources backed by an API gateway for your service. The frontend would just need to know the service URL to query the data from the api.